# Inserindo Id de uma chave estrangeira em um Banco de Dados Relacional

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Bom dia.

Sou iniciante em Banco de Dados e programação e tenho uma duvida, qual a query para recuperar o id para inserir em uma tabela com chave estrangeira?

Estou utilizando o banco de dados MYSQL.

Exemplo, eu tenho a tabela "postagem", na tabela postagem tem os campos " idPostagem", "Titulo",  "Conteudo" e "IdCategoria" (Chave estrangeira)

E na tabela "Categoria" tem os campos "IdCategoria" e "Nome".

Vamos supor que no painel de postagem aparece para preencher o nome, titulo, conteudo e uma combobox com a lista das Categorias.

Na inserção seria assim "

```
INSERT INTO postagem (titulo, conteudo, idCategoria)
VALUES ('Titulo', 'Conteudo', idCategoria);
```

Vamos supor que o usuario selecionou a categoria "Policial", como eu faço para recuperar o ID dessa categoria da tabela Categoria e inserir o ID na tabela "Postagem"

Desculpa se a pergunta foi simples ou boba, mas estou começando agora e enrosquei nessa parte.

Obrigado a todos!

Comment: você poderia criar uma subconsulta pra retornar o id da categoria desejada ou então quando você mostra na tela para o usuario qual a categoria você traz também o id da categoria, e quando for dar o insert você consegue resgatar esses valores! Você esta utilizando qual linguagem de back-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que seu nome da tabela Categoria seja único:

```
INSERT INTO postagem (idPostagem, titulo, conteudo, idCategoria)
VALUES (<Seu idPostagem>, 'Titulo', 'Conteudo', 
(select idCategoria from Categoria where nome = 'Policial'));
```

Caso seu nome possa não ser único, você precisa passar o id vindo da tela. Mas esta subquery resolve bem o problema se o retorno dela não houver mais de 1 valor.

Comment: Caso o banco de Dados seja o Postgresql, será a mesma query ou tem diferença?

Comment: @FelipePachecoPaulucio Não conheço muito bem o postgree, mas não acredito em alguma particularidade nisso.